# Upload file in MVC4 always get null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have upload in view using

```
<div class="SearchArea">

@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Noun", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{ 
     @Html.ValidationSummary();
     <ol>
     <li class="lifile">
     <input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
     <span class="field-validation-error" id="spanfile"></span>
     </li>
     </ol>
     <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
}   

</div>
```

and the Fileupload method looks like

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase input)
{
    if (input.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(input.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images"), fileName);
        input.SaveAs(path);
    }
```

I always get input is null, my routeconfig looks like (I compile wcf with the same project):

```
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // For general and WCF Configuration 
    routes.MapRoute(
      "Default",
      "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
      new { controller = "^(?!ClassesWebService).*" });

    routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("ClassesWebService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(WebService.IClassesWebService)));
```

any idea how to solve that

Comment: Try to see the value of `Request.Files["fileToUpload"]` in your action. If this value is also null then see what do you have in `Request.Files`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your names mismatch.  Here you have the name `file`:

```
<input type="file" id="fileToUpload" name="file" />
```

And here you have the name `input`:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase input)
```

Rename one to the other.